# Ember-Cli import js without bower

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, jquery-plugins, ember-cli

I should import this plug-in that is not present in bower: [ImageTiltEffect](https://github.com/codrops/ImageTiltEffect/), in my ember-cli app.
I already created the sub-directory in the vendor directory, imported this in my Brocfile and added `"TiltFx": true` in my `.jshintrc` file.
About the last point I am not very sure if it is done in the right way, btw my question is: after these steps, how can I use this plug-in? How can I call its init function from my ember code?
Thank you in advance for the answers!

Answer (score 2):

Import the library in ember-cli-build.js:

```
app.import('vendor/tiltfx.js');
return app.toTree();
```

In your .jshintrc file, add TiltFx as a predefined global:

```
"predef": [
  "document",
  "window",
  "-Promise",
  "TiltFx"
],
```

You should now be able to use TiltFx.

**component.js**

```
onDidInsertElement: function() {
  new TiltFx(element, options)
}.on('didInsertElement'),
```